# How to call a method inside another method's object (list)? C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to figure out how this is possible (if it is at all). Code looks basically like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public Method1()
    {
        List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
        mylist.  /*how can I call Method2?*/
    }

    public Method2()
    {
        /*automation code for changing sequence of the UI objects
        (action)*/
    }
}
```

I am able to use built-in methods like `Sort()`, `Add()` all of them after

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System.Collections;
using namespace System.Collections.Generic;
```

and so on, but I was wondering if I have to put `Method2()` inside another class, import it as a namespace and then use it on the object `mylist` inside `Method1()`.

Comment: `mylist` is a List<T> instance, hence "Something" in `mylist.Something()` has to be a method provided by List<T>, or an extension method compatible with the List<T> type. But you have explained so little about what you want to achieve with your code there, i am anything but sure whether extension methods is what you are looking for.

Comment: *Why* do you want to do `myList.Method2();`?

Comment: Yes, you can create an extension method for List<T>(or maybe even for IEnumerable<T>) and move the code from Method2 into that method.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: nooooo. Please don't advise people to put extension methods on Microsoft classes. It was certainly useful for Microsoft to implement LINQ and to separate LINQ into different DLLs. In 90+% of the cases I don't want libraries that hide their implementation behind Microsoft classes.

Answer (score 4):

You'd do it the opposite way around: instead of trying to give the object a new method, you give the method the object:

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    public void Method1()
    {
        List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
        Method2(mylist); /*how can I call Method2?*/
    }

    public void Method2(List<string> list)
    {
        //does something with list      
    }
}
```

Technically there's also the possibility of extension methods. But you really want to understand why Microsoft made extension methods and what they are good for. You don't just spam extension methods, just because it's technically possible.

Trust me, when you type `mylist.` you really want to see only Microsoft methods, because Microsoft provided the `List<T>` class. You don't want to see thousands of methods everyone thought could be useful.

Comment: You need `void` or other return type on methods.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: that's true. Didn't notice that in OPs code.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Thank you so much. I'll provide more info about my problem: There's a list of ImgTags. I created an empty list, then I was going through the members of that list and used .Add() method to append that empty list. I have a method with action for changing the sequence of those ImgTags. I just want to compare if two lists have 1) same number of members 2) Sequence matters. That's basically it. I hope you understand now why I wanted it :)

Comment: @diskoo: `class ListComparer{ bool Compare(List<T> a, List<T> b) { ... } }` and then put in your two lists for comparison.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void  Method1()
    {
        List<string> mylist = new List<string>();

        /*how can I call Method2?*/
        Method2(mylist);
    }

    public void Method2(List<string> mylist)
    {
        //does something with my list
    }
}
```